# How to easily plot two different DataFrame on the same plot?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's imagine I get the stock market of Tesla and Microsoft and I want to print the close price for both.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

start = '2010-01-01'
end = '2020-12-31'
tesla = yf.download('TSLA', start=start, end=end)
microsoft = yf.download('MSFT', start=start, end=end)
```

I can easily plot each on its own plot:

```
microsoft.Close.plot()
```

Or use axes to hack them on the same plot, but I don't get the legend:

```
ax = microsoft.Close.plot()
ax = tesla.Close.plot(ax=ax)
```

Or I can merge my two DataFrame

```
# Ugly but elegant...
frames = []
for u in ['microsoft', 'tesla']:
    df = globals()[u]
    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[u] * len(df.columns), list(df.columns.values)])
    frames.append(df)
df = pd.merge(*frames, on=["Date"])

df[[('tesla', 'Open'), ('microsoft', 'Open')]].plot()
```

The latter solution seems better since I am simply plotting whatever I want, but the merge process seems cumbersome.

Any better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the data from both stocks directly from yfinance and plot the open data

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

start = '2010-01-01'
end = '2020-12-31'
stocks = ['TSLA', 'MSFT']

data = yf.download(stocks, start=start, end=end)
data['Open'].plot()
```

Comment: Well, you kind of answer my question, but this is an X-Y answer :( I took stocks as an example, this is not my real use case...

Comment: Oh, ok, I did not understand that at first. If the issue is just the legend, for first case you can just use `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and `plt.legend(['MSFT', 'TSLA'])` to add the legend in the plot.